# SQL Server trigger on a view to start a procedure

Tags: sql-server, view, triggers, sql-update

I have a view and I'd like to implement a trigger or procedure to sum up all values in one column, store it with a timestamp and a ID inside of a new table so i get a aggregation over time.

Each time the view gets updated, the trigger should start the procedure so each change gets logged.

The actual problem is, that the view gets updated, but my table where all the information should be stored does not get any new rows inserted.

View code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TOTAL_ERRORS]
AS
    SELECT        
        Fehlerart, 
        COUNT(Fehlerart) AS Total_Errors, 
        FehlerartEN, 
        COUNT(FehlerartEN) AS Total_Errors_EN, 
        FehlerartDE, 
        COUNT(FehlerartDE) AS Total_Errors_DE
    FROM            
        [dbo].[AggregateOnError]
    WHERE        
        ActdateIN >= DATEADD(DAY, - 4, GETDATE()) 
        AND Status <> '0' 
        AND FehlerartDE <> 'Blank' 
        AND FehlerartEN <> 'Blank' 
        AND Fehlerart <> 'NULL'
    GROUP BY 
        Fehlerart, FehlerartEN, FehlerartDE
```

Trigger code:

```
USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Execute_Sum_Total_Errors]
ON [Database].[dbo].[TOTAL_ERRORS]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC Sum_Total_Errors;
END;
```

Procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [user].Sum_Total_Errors
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NeueSumme INT;
    SELECT @NeueSumme = SUM(Total_Errors) FROM TOTAL_ERRORS;
    
    DECLARE @AktuellerZeitstempel DATETIME;
    SET @AktuellerZeitstempel = GETDATE();

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Aggregate_Static_v2 WHERE Aggregate_Sum = @NeueSumme)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Aggregate_Static_v2 (Aggregate_Sum, ActualDate) VALUES (@NeueSumme, @AktuellerZeitstempel);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Aggregate_Static_v2 SET Aggregate_Sum = @NeueSumme, ActualDate = @AktuellerZeitstempel WHERE Aggregate_Sum = @NeueSumme;
    END
END;
```

Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Aggregate_Static_v2] 
(
    [ID]              BIGINT   NULL,
    [Aggregate_Sum]   BIGINT   NULL,
    [ActualDate]      DATETIME NULL
);
```

Comment: Don't store aggregates that you can compute.

Comment: Wow, my mind is blown that you can have triggers on views! But i think you misunderstand how these work. Normal "update" as in, underlying data changes won't trigger the view trigger. Only direct updates of the VIEW will. So, you should probably just put the trigger on the base table (and remove the INSTEAD OF part). Also, your aggregation makes absolutely no sense. What are you tracking, how the SUM changes?

Comment: What's the point of aggregating the same columns you're using in the group by?

Comment: so i need to specify my problem further. From two base tables i am creating the view '[dbo].[AggregateOnError]'.
Because one of the base tables has a fixed amount of rows, the column "Fehlerart" has a fixed amount on possible values, so by grouping the view [dbo].[TOTAL_ERRORS] based on this columns the counted values vary and that is the information i want to safe with an actual timestamp.

So from my point of view i can't use the base table, i have to use the view.

Is there maybe another way to reach my goal?

Comment: The point of aggregating the column 'Total_Errors' is, to get a reference on the time like a live counter with historic values.
ex. 
today on 26.10.23 12:29 the amount was 178
today on 26.10.23 12:25 the amount was 190
today on 26.10.23 12:20 the amount was 170
...

Comment: The desired result is really not clear. Do you want just a log of the total error count every time a row is inserted? What happens if rows are deleted? Why is your procedure doing `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Aggregate_Static_v2 WHERE Aggregate_Sum = @NeueSumme)` what is the relevance if the sum value already existed?

Comment: the desired result is basically just a log of the sum from 'Total_Errors' for each change in the calculated sum with a timestamp for each change.

Comment: Maybe you should be looking at a temporal table implementation with system_versioning

Comment: I really did not get how triggers work, but the solution was implementing the trigger on one of the base tables but getting the desired information from the view that works just as expected so thanks for your help, I wouldn't have understood it otherwise.